# How to pass multiple edittext values into a Arraylist and then send it to another activity?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am trying to pass 5 edittext values into a `Arraylist` and then send it to another activity. I use intent to send it to the next activity, but it keeps crashing. I get this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array

I think the way I add the values into the arraylist is wrong or something is wrong with sending the `arraylist` in the intent.

Activity 1:

```
EditText p1, p2, p3, p4, p5;
ArrayList<String> playerList = new ArrayList<>();
BootstrapButton btnStart;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnStart = (BootstrapButton) findViewById(R.id.start);
    p1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player1);
    p2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player2);
    p3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player3);
    p4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player4);
    p5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player5);

    playerList.add(p1.getText().toString());
    playerList.add(p2.getText().toString());
    playerList.add(p3.getText().toString());
    playerList.add(p4.getText().toString());
    playerList.add(p5.getText().toString());

    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
            myIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("player_list", playerList);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }

    });
  }
```

Activity 2:

```
TextView playerName;
ArrayList<String> playerList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    playerName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playerName);

    Intent myIntent = getIntent();
    if(myIntent != null){
        playerList = myIntent.getStringArrayListExtra("player_list");
        playerName.setText(playerList.get(0));
    }
  }
```

When I am using it like this with the hardcoded array values it doesn't crash and the value will be printed out correctly in the next activity.

Activity 1:

```
String[] array1={"asd","fgh","dcf","dg","ere","dsf"};
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("player_list", array1);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Activity 2:

```
    Intent myIntent = getIntent();
    if(myIntent != null){
        String[] players = myIntent.getStringArrayExtra("player_list");
        playerName.setText(players[2]);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Error!");
    }
```

What I want to do is having an `Arraylist` like this `["p1","p2","p3","p4","p5"]` and then in the next activity retrieving the `arraylist` and printing out a random name from that array.

Comment: Is there anything in the edit texts? you are immediately getting values from the edit texts as soon as the activity starts. If there's nothing in them then you would essentially be adding empty strings to an array.

Comment: is `playerList` declared?

Comment: Also, when you are testing them, you are using an `Array`, and in your actual implementation you are using an `ArrayList`

Comment: Yeah, do a test run with an ArrayList

Comment: you are also using `getStringArrayExtra` try using `getStringArrayListExtra`

Comment: It’s confusing, you have an Array[] but you’re trying to serialize/parcel an ArrayList. If you end up using an ArrayList, you have to use `getStringArrayList(KEY)` from a bundle/argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `intent.putStringArrayListExtra` in Activity 1 to send and `getStringArrayListExtra()` in Activity 2 to retrieve the String ArrayList.

Here is the code to do so:

Activity 1:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnStart = (BootstrapButton) findViewById(R.id.start);
    p1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player1);
    p2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player2);
    p3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player3);
    p4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player4);
    p5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player5);

    playerList.add(p1.getText().toString());
    playerList.add(p2.getText().toString());
    playerList.add(p3.getText().toString());
    playerList.add(p4.getText().toString());
    playerList.add(p5.getText().toString());

    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
            myIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("player_list", playerList);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }

    });
  }
```

Activity 2:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    playerName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playerName);

    Intent myIntent = getIntent();
    if(myIntent != null){
            ArrayList<String> players = myIntent.getStringArrayListExtra("player_list");
            playerName.setText(players.get(0));
        }else{
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
      }
```

Also make sure playerList is declared and initialized. Your code does not show it being declared nor initialized.

Answer (score 2):

Use `getStringArrayListExtra` not `getStringArrayExtra`

```
if(myIntent != null){
        String[] players = myIntent.getStringArrayListExtra("player_list");
        playerName.setText(players[2]);
    }
```